# Display Categories Assigned to a WooCommerce Product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories, terms

I am using WooCommerce with SuperStore theme. In meta.php file is this line,

```
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
```

which displays the assigned categories to the post, but not in hierarchical order. I want to display these in hierarchical order.

I also found these piece of code, after some changes it is displaying the categories in correct order, but I need a new line tag if the top parent class is other then the previous category.

```
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    // get the term IDs assigned to post.
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    // separator between links
    $separator = ' » ';

    if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
        $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
        $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

        // display post categories
        echo  $terms;
    }
```

Example:

Shoes
-Kids(sub)

Kids
-Shoes(sub)

Now it is displayed as: Shoes » Kids » Kids » Shoes

I need it to display as:

Shoes » Kids

Kids » Shoes

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with creating a list with

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

changing style to list, then style it with CSS to my needs :)

```
<?php 

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    // get the term IDs assigned to post.
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

        $tophelp_categories = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=<span class="posted_in">Kategóriák:</span>&style=list&echo=0&depth=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );

        // display post categories
        echo ($tophelp_categories);
    }

?>
```