# Only return taxonomies that are linked to a category & product

Tags: plugins, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

What's the best way, to return taxonomies, but only taxonomies that are linked to a product, within the category, I have a heirachial taxonomy, I want to get all the top level options, once an option is picked, I want to get all the children, but only the children that are linked to a product.

Is this possible?

Currently I'm just getting the immediate children of the first term picked, I don't know how to filter out the ones that have no matches.

This is the second request:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'tyre', array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'child_of'      => $term_id,
    'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty
));
```

Is there a way to extend this to something like this:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'tyre', array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'category'      => 'tyres',
    'only_linked_to_products' => true,
    'child_of'      => $term_id,
    'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty
));
```

Obviously I've just invented these two properties, but it would help illustrate what I'm trying to do

Comment: Setting `hide_empty` to `true` will - as the name suggests - only return terms that are assigned to a post.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, okay I feel stupid - but what about only matching specific categories?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Let's say I have a taxonomy that's selectable because it's attached to a post - but that post (product) is in a category that isn't in the current category, so I don't want it to be selectable, does that make more sense?

Comment: Hi Shannon Please Refer to below link [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140738/164966](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140738/164966)

Comment: @KaranNaimishTrivedi - I don't think that's what I'm after, I want to return taxonomies, not categories, but I want the taxonomies to be filtered by a specific category

Answer (score 0):

This will find all terms in custom taxonomy `underkategorier` and then will show terms with post from chosen category.

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array('name'=>'underkategorier'),'object'); 

foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy->name, 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'underkategorier','term'=>$term->slug, "cat"=>10);
        $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        $article_count = $myquery->post_count; 
        echo $term->name.' '.$article_count; //with empty ones
        if ($article_count){
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li>".$term->name.' '.$article_count."</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I feel like this is a very heavy request, performing multuiple searches per taxonomy...

Comment: @ShannonHochkins there is other way by fetching content using wpdb queries.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Please Refer link
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/master/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php